# How to prevent Facebook from showing your likes, comments on friend's news feed?

Tags: facebook

Currently, whenever I like or comment on Facebook, in my friends’ news feed it shows as “Pradeep Simha likes John's photo,” “Pradeep Simha commented on Jay's status” etc. How do I prevent this from happening?

Are there any privacy settings for this actions?

Answer (score 1):

When you post status there is a select button on the right bottom side which brings up a menu specifying your audience: public,  friends, select person/s etc., something like that, I try and limit posts sometimes but I don't know if it works. 
I once posted a comment that I though was private on an article published on another site, it was very embarrassing.... just as I posted I notice a small  checkbox under the comment field saying,  share on facebook, and then noticed that I was actually logged into that site with my Facebook ID.
I wanted to die. 
I managed to delete the comment on my wall but it had gone onto the FB newsfeed, publicly!
There seems to be no way to delete newsfeed to limit damage in such circumstances, but I think it is possible to select your audience before you make a status update, tho not like and comments. 
You can only filter your own news feed.

Answer (score -2):

just do what i do. create an account with no friends that you use to bash businesses.  I too thought it was odd that every post i did showed up on my friends pages.  I got ripped off and yelled at a business on FB and to my surprise my friends all could read it.  FB probably does this to keep us nice.

Comment: What is the purpose of opening such FB account?

Comment: @Pradeep Simha well there are a lot of things happening politically like the Trump Biden conspiracies and covid deniers; if you want to speak up against them, it does not feel comfortable letting your friends/family see everything into your personal internet life, even when it's technically "public" because "visible in public" is not the same as "show all my friends and family".